# php session and cookie values maximum length

Tags: php, session, cookies

What is maximum value size for php session's and cookie's? that is maximum how much byte can put in  him

```
$_SESSION['key'] = "here what maximum bytes are possible";

$_COOKIE['key'] = "here what maximum bytes are possible";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum size of a php session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649907/maximum-size-of-a-php-session)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SESSION` you can save unlimited amount of data, no real limit for that...

`$_COOKIE` is I guess under 4000 bytes...(Includes date, name, value, expiry)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a great idea to use a session to store a huge amount of information in it. You can however, store as much as information as you want in a session since it's just a file that is stored on the server. But if you want to store information in a high-scale amount, such as text for example, I would recommend you to use a database. And never store images as blobs in a database since it will just overload it.