# codeIgniter : losing session data after login

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

In codeigniter after login I am storing all the data into session and redirecting to forum controller. But I am losing all values in forum controller.

When I try after reducing some values from session it works perfectly.

**Now my question is** - why this is happening? Is there any upper limit of values to be store in session in codeIgniter?

Even I try to search I found like

```
redirect('forum', 'refresh');
```

But it is not working. And my project is half developed so I can't use "PHP Native Session class" of codeignter.

Comment: You can use the native session class, it integrates seemlessly. You might have to add one method to the class maximum. (I did at least)

Comment: @jadkik94: as i already mention i cant use native session class as i already developed most of the modules and cant go and changes each files.

Comment: Turn your config to save sessions to database. See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation**:
By default CodeIgniter stores the session data in a cookie, which has an upper limit of 2KB-4KB in size depending on browser.
If you are trying to store more than 4KB of data in the session you will start running into issues.

**Solution**:
The easiest solution is to store the session details in the DB.The [CodeIgniter session documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) details the process for storing the session in the DB.it's a matter of setting up a table, and changing a couple of config parameters. Below are the changes you need to do-

Update below variable in Config file (application/config/config.php):

```
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']   = 'ci_sessions';
```

Created new table for storing session-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
user_data text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

For more info:http://goo.gl/YPllj0

Answer (score 7):

By default CodeIgniter stores the session data in a cookie, which has an upper limit of 4KB in size. If you are trying to store more than 4KB of data in the session you will start running into issues.

The easiest solution is probably to store the session details in the DB. The [CodeIgniter session documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) details the process for storing the session in the DB - it's a matter of setting up a table, and changing a couple of config parameters.

Answer (score 4):

The CI session stores everything in a cookie, with optional encryption. So [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213199/php-session-and-cookie-values-maximum-length) it is possible to reach that limit. That's if you store something like 2K bytes; if it is just login information, that shouldn't be a problem. If you do use something as big as that, well, I guess you shouldn't.

Anyway, I don't think this is the problem, as I had a similar problem (I don't remember the exact cause of this). The solution I found was to use the Native PHP Session class, and added one method to it: all_userdata or whatever it was called. With that, everything worked just like it would with the normal Session (no need to change anything).

Comment: @jadkik94 I know you did this a while ago, but before using the Native PHP Session class, did you try using the CI session DB table (the accepted answer)? If so, did you understand why it failed? In my case it still loses the session randomly. Can you describe the all_userdata method you added?

Comment: @Armfoot I don't think I had tried the database session. The all_userdara method just returned the `$_SESSION` array. Anyway I think in CI 3.0 they revamped the whole Session class. See [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-drivers) if you're using the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, after some tests (with https and http in localhost) the error comes for that issue and not having properly set the $config['cookie_secure'], so you can try changing in config.php:

```
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE; // if is not under https, or true if you use https
```

Cheers!