# Using CodeIgniter with normal PHP sessions, where to add session_start();

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble using CodeIgniters implementation of sessions getting deleted after a redirect so I'm reverting to normal PHP sessions.

Where would the best place for `session_start();` be, assuming I want it called on every page without adding it to every controller constructor?

I'd guess putting it at the top of main index.php would be would work ok, would just like to make sure that doing this doesn't break anything or if there's a better/standard place to put it?

Comment: today i ask this question just check it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122848/codeigniter-loosing-session-data-after-login

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried using the database and a few other solutions for the session loss stuff but to no avail so I just want to switch back to normal sessions.

Comment: i think that is not a good call...

Comment: Normal PHP sessions do everything I require so why work on trying to work around a problem when I don't have to have that problem at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is why I always use an extended controller that contains application wide code.

To extend the codeigniter controller, place this code in a file called MY_Controller.php and save it to the core folder.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        session_start();
    }
}
```

If you decide to use this solution all your controllers will need to extend MY_Controller.

[Creating Core System Classes](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution, I don't want to be going back and editing a lot of files though, will keep it in consideration for my next project.

Answer (score 3):

YOu can easily put them in `index.php`.  THis is the entry point to your codeigniter application and is called on every request.

although this is generally not recommended becuase when you upgrade your codeigniter versions you will need to remember to copy your customizations to index.php.

instead of index.php, you could use a prerequest [hook](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like a hook is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** use `session_start();` directly in codeigniter.
Instead you must use:

```
$this->library->load('session');
$this->session->set_userdata(array('name' => 'name','age' =>
 'age','etc' => 'etc');
```

Comment: Of course you can. It just isn't the recommended way.