# How many session variables can I use in one session_start in PHP?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have multiple session variables. How many times do I have to call `session_start` in a page? If only once, is it going to account for four session variables e.g. `$_SESSION['a'],$_SESSION['login'],$_SESSION['b'],$_SESSION['c']`?

Comment: `session_start` is just to enable the session system, you can add _a lot_ of keys to the global session array

Comment: yah, that means you only need to call session_start once in each page

Comment: I want to use these session variables. How many of them can I use, if I use session_start at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Okay, I get it. So, if I initiate various session variables throughout the page, I need to call session_start once. Right?

Comment: @good_daddy See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649907/maximum-size-of-a-php-session

Comment: I followed the link, so I think the answer to my last question in the comments is 'yes'?

Comment: @good_daddy Yes. As long as you start the session at the very top of your script so you don't get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (..)". You can store maximum 128 mb by default.

Comment: Thanks. So, I am putting it over <!DOCTYPE  html>

Comment: @good_daddy yep. put it at line 1 or so

Comment: @JimL - Comments are for discussion of the question and are considered second-class citizens on SO.  As  you have answered the question - if you post it as an answer, I will upvote.

Comment: @cale_b I know - normally I don't have time to write a proper answer so I just comment where I see I can provide some constructive info. This weekend I'm alone with the kids so SO time slots are rare and short :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the session you need to call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION` variables. 
To avoid errors like

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (..)
```

call session_start() on the very top of your script.

By default the maximum size of the session is the maximum memory of your script - **128mb**. For further information this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649907/maximum-size-of-a-php-session).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) once.  It will account for all of your $_SESSION variables.

Within the session, you can have practically as many session variables as you like.

Best practice is to call `session_start` at the top of your script, before any output is generated.