# how much data can a session hold safely in php?

Tags: session

While developing a shopping cart how much data can i allow a session variable to hold for safe usage?

When a visitor of my site views different products and features without registering how much information can the session hold safely?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649907/maximum-size-of-a-php-session