# session_start() in PHP 4

Tags: php, session, php4

I always think that I am the unluckiest guy, because I have to maintain very horrible code written by some one else.  But after going through some of the forums, I realized I am not alone.

This code was written before I started working here, now I am maintaining it.  I always keep asking that we should allocate time to rewrite the code, but no one cares.

The question I am about to ask, you can comment that it is absolutely horrible, but rewriting the whole code is not an option.

Here is the scenario.

The whole website is written in PHP 4 (60% of website is in index.php, don't know why), so every now and then there is session_start().  Due to that, the session gets reset very frequently and it used to log out the user.  I went ahead and commented out session_start().  It stopped logging out the user when he is in the website.  Now there are some new issues.

Did I do something wrong by commenting the session_start()?

EDIT:
I saw documentation about session_start, may be I did not add some additional information in question. I did google search "session size limit PHP" the following is the link. stackoverflow.com/questions/217420/ideal-php-session-size. So what happens if there is too much data in the session? – user110093

Comment: It would seem that yes, you did do something wrong. We have no idea what without seeing some code though...

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is the right place to ask that. I think the answer would be that whenever we type even a single character into a source file, it is briefly broken. I think the error would be in releasing code without thorough testing. Whether or not there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to achieve would depend a lot on the code.

Comment: It highly depends on what session is used for. It might be used for authentication, for storing data etc. Please try to find $_SESSION in the code and understand the purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the php documentation

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

So what you are describing in the following should not be happening:

> so every now and then there is session_start(). Due to that the session gets reset very frequently and it used to log out the user.

If I were you, I would delve deeper and find out the reason why sessions are reset. `session_start()` should not be the root of this problem.

Comment: I saw that in documentation, may be I did not add some additional information in  question. I did google search "session size limit PHP" the following is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217420/ideal-php-session-size. So what happens if there is too much data in the session?