# PHP - Session object destruction failed

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-3.4

I'm facing a strange problem on Symfony: basically sometimes, without any apparent reason, the user is unable to load web pages until I restart php-fpm or until he changes its `PHPSESSID` loading a new session. Anyway his session is still working properly after fpm is restarted.

At the same time, I got 2 warnings from PHP:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Session object destruction failed in
>   /home/unix/releases/1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
>   on line 145
>
> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to decode session object.
>   Session has been destroyed in
>   /home/unix/releases/1/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php
>   on line 145

Consider that we are talking about a private website used maximum from 2-3 users concurrently, but it might also happen if just 1 user is navigating on it.

Current setup is

- Debian 9.4 stretch 4.14.0-0.bpo.3-amd64
- php-fpm 7.1.15
- Symfony 3.4.4

I'm able to reproduce the issue using [apache ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html) calling different URLs concurrently using the same session id. Of course after *N* requests I got timeout:

```
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 872 requests completed
```

Now I'm trying to check php configuration but actually is quite "normal" without special settings so I don't know what should I try or check. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you save entities inside of the session? I had a similar problem once where the session got too big and could not be decoded anymore. Try saving IDs instead of entities.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Vyctorya - I'm currently saving objects in session. I thought the same but still I can't figure out why it happens after e.g. 872 requests and not directly at first request..

Comment: Maybe you reach max var allowed (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12916515/8411841) or max session size (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4649934/8411841)?

Comment: Hey, check this issue - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18574

Comment: Also, you can try to use [PdoSessionHandler to Store Sessions in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html)

Comment: Also, you can try to upgrade yours PHP to actual stable version - 7.2.x. There was some similar issues with 7.1.

Comment: And what are you have in `session.auto_start` in php.ini

Comment: And the last question - what is about free disk storage?

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. @Vyctorya both things you mentioned don't seem to be related to my problem. @EugeneR the `session.auto_start` is disabled, disk has enough free space, that issue seems to be related to something else and regarding sessions in DB I actually prefer to keep it as it is. Anyway I will try to upgrade (or even downgrade) PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

Finally I was able to find the problem. Basically it comes from Symfony itself since by default seems that it also implements kind of [garbage collection logic](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#configuring-garbage-collection) in `Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/StrictSessionHandler.php`

```
public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
    return $this->handler->gc($maxlifetime);
}
```

This wouldn't be a problem if `/var/lib/php/sessions/` directory belongs to the same user defined in `php.ini` or if it has *read* permissions, but by default that directory belongs to `root` user and is not readable (so files cannot be listed). This causes an exception when Symfony tries to call the garbage collector on current session handler.

---

## The solution

There are two solutions: setting

```
session:
    gc_probability: ~
```

in Symfony `config.yml` or adding *read* permission to PHP sessions directory (or eventually change relative user using the same defined in `php.ini`). Hope it might help someone.